# How do I change the grey background in emails to a white background?

Tags: email, rwd, magento-1.9

I want to change the ugly grey background in my emails(templates). I'm using the rwd theme. Is there an easy way to do it? Nothing to fancy just practical. I already tried to change the background in email-inline.scss but nothing happened. Exte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the email styles are all located in:

```
skin/frontend/base/default/css/email-inline.css
```